# Issues with first programming game (javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm teaching myself programming. I just started a Hangman game in JS a few days ago. I'm having trouble figuring out whether or not the list value the user clicks is one of the values in the word they're trying to guess. I think it's an issue with "global and local variables", but I'm not sure how to get around it without including everything in one function. My code is below, sorry for the noob mistakes, I really appreciate anyone who can give me a little advice. Thanks!

```
var wordBank = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'monkey', 'radish'];
var word;

    // start game on click and choose random word from wordBank
function startGame() {
  $("#hangman").hide('slow');
  $("#start").click(function(){
    var word = wordBank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank.length)];
    var wordLength = word.length;

    var underscores = "";
    for(i=0; i<wordLength; i++) {
        underscores = underscores + "_ "
    }
    // now variable underscores has the underscores.
    $("#word").html(underscores);
  });

  // get list value for the letter chosen
  $(".alpha li").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).text();
    // see if character clicked matches index of a letter in the word
    if(word.indexOf(text) >= 0) {
      alert("Correct Letter!");
    } else {
      alert("Wrong!");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `word` isn't out of scope for your click functions if that is what you were worried about. what exactly is happening? can you show relevant dom?

Comment: You should check the API docs for the click function before posting here.  Try googling it.

Comment: so what's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: I cannot get what the question is?

Comment: You assign a value to the wrong `word` variable... See my answer.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you're re-declaring `word` in the `#start` click handler.

Comment: You should roll back your last edit.  You removed all the code that pertains to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a value to the **wrong** `word` variable.

Remove the keyword `var` that comes before `word` in your first click handler:

```
word = wordBank[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank.length)];
```

---

That is the quick way to fix your problem.

You *should* try to avoid global variables, but we'll leave that discussion for your 2nd program ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to declare it up above the function startGame? Or is that unnecessary?

Comment: Declaring it at the top will work.  This will make it a _global variable_, which is discouraged.  But... We won't worry about that yet, since this is your first program.